# Finite non-zero determinant constraint?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

Assume I want to train a multivariable normal distribution on given data set T. One definition of multivariable normal distribution is this:

> A random vector X has a (multivariate) normal distribution if it can be expressed in the form $ X = M v+ b$ for some matrix M and some real vector b, where v is a random vector whose components are independent N (0, 1) random variables

So using this definition, I want to train a Gaussian distribution on Training set T, as fallow: minimize $1/K \sum^K_i (X -x_i )^2 $ w.r.t $M$ and $b$ where $x_i\in T$.  Therefore here I am training a linear model to learn a gaussion distribution.

Now, the model is actually learn as the loss function converge to zero and the model fit the data. However training leads to a covariance matrix, $MM^T$, which has determinant equal to zero. This means I cannot normalized this pdf which is not good. I understand that this might be a sing that gaussion model is not a good model for this data. But still I am wonder if I can put constrain on $ M$ or write it in a form that assure finite non-zero determinant?

Comment: "Square matrix M * M" makes no sense.  Your equation $Y=MX+b,$ the dimension of $b$ (call is $n$) and the assumption $M$ is square completely determine all dimensions of these vectors and matrices. Given any vectors $Y,$ $X,$ and $b,$ there exist plenty of invertible matrices $M$ for which $Y=MX+b.$  In two or more dimensions, the determinant of $M$ can be literally any real number (positive, negative, or zero). This is not a statistical problem--it's an underdetermined (and very simple) problem of linear algebra.  Are you sure you have described your situation accurately?

Comment: @whuber I have updated my question, you were right the first version of not clear.

Comment: Search our site for good posts on "regularization."